# How to configure minishift for user access

Tags: minishift

I would like to configure minishift for multiple users instead of using the default developer account to access the console and deploy the applications. I am thinking of an LDAP or Linux user management system where the users are created with default credentials and once they access the minishift environment and login they can be forced to change their passwords. The users created/maintained by the system can login and deploy the applications instead of anybody that uses the developer or admin default credentials.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [product page](https://www.okd.io/minishift/)

> Minishift is a tool that helps you run OKD locally by launching a single-node OKD cluster inside a virtual machine. With Minishift you can try out OKD or develop with it, day-to-day, on your local machine.

What you are describing here is a shared build system for a team of developers. This is not what minishift is meant for. You will have to [install an OKD cluster yourself on dedicated machine(s)](https://docs.okd.io/latest/welcome/index.html) (you probably want to have several of them).